# Не подсвечивается синтаксис openCV в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

У меня не подсвечивается синтаксис openCV, хотя библиотека установленная. Помогите решить проблему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите какой-нибудь плагин

Comment: Там только openCV image viewer..

Comment: Посмотрел в плагинах - что-то `OpenCV` не нашел. А как он вообще должен подсвечиваться? Может быть и без плагинов можно разобраться.

Comment: По картинке - как-будто PyCharm не подсказывает функции в этом модуле. Если так, то это с PyCharm бывает и как правило через некоторое время проходит.

Comment: Ладно, буду ждать.

Comment: Это баг в PyCharm https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35691/Code-completion-doesnt-work-for-cv2-module